# docker port mapping is not working on windows 10 even after the port is made free

Tags: windows, docker, port

I have a service running on port 9090 and 9091 for which the container is up and running

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
f916800a7446        x1               "catalina.sh run"        5 seconds ago       
Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:9090->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9091->8081/tcp   x1
```

but when I open link in browser page is unreachable.

netstat for ports 9090 and 9091

```
λ netstat -ano | findstr :9090
   TCP    0.0.0.0:9090           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12824
   TCP    [::1]:9090             [::]:0                 LISTENING       12824




 λ netstat -ano | findstr :9091
   TCP    0.0.0.0:9091           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12824
   TCP    [::1]:9091             [::]:0                 LISTENING       12824
```

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the service itself is running on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) and not just localhost.

Comment: Go into the container and try doing netstat, curl etc.